# How to use multiple Table Type parameters in a SQL procedure to filter data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that receives multiple table type parameters and I want to filter the data (efficiently) based on those parameters but only if the parameters have at least one record inside them.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MySproc]
    ,@P1 TableType1 READONLY
    ,@P2 TableType2 READONLY
    ,@P3 TableType1 READONLY
    ,@P4 TableType2 READONLY
    ,@P5 TableType1 READONLY
    ,@P6 TableType2 READONLY
AS 
    BEGIN
      select * from MyTable1 t
      where 
        (not exists(select top 1 1 from @P1) or exists(select top 1 1 from @P1 p where p.Id = t.Type1))
        (not exists(select top 1 1 from @P2) or exists(select top 1 1 from @P2 p where p.Id = t.Type2))
        (not exists(select top 1 1 from @P3) or exists(select top 1 1 from @P3 p where p.Id = t.Type3))
        (not exists(select top 1 1 from @P4) or exists(select top 1 1 from @P4 p where p.Id = t.Type4))
        (not exists(select top 1 1 from @P5) or exists(select top 1 1 from @P5 p where p.Id = t.Type5))
        (not exists(select top 1 1 from @P6) or exists(select top 1 1 from @P6 p where p.Id = t.Type6))
END;
```

Comment: Have you actually run into a performance issue? There is usually no need to pre-optimise SQL unless you have actually hit an issue as the engine these days is pretty good at generating a good execution plan.

Comment: `top 1` is unnecessary in an `exists` and will be elided by the compiler

Answer (score 0):

You should use dynamic SQL here, something like this:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MySproc]
     @P1 TableType1 READONLY
    ,@P2 TableType2 READONLY
    ,@P3 TableType1 READONLY
    ,@P4 TableType2 READONLY
    ,@P5 TableType1 READONLY
    ,@P6 TableType2 READONLY
AS 
BEGIN

    declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'select * from MyTable1 t where 1=1';


     if exists(select * from @P1) set @sql = @sql + ' and exists(select * from @P1 p where p.Id = t.Type1)'
     if exists(select * from @P2) set @sql = @sql + ' and exists(select * from @P2 p where p.Id = t.Type2)'
     if exists(select * from @P3) set @sql = @sql + ' and exists(select * from @P3 p where p.Id = t.Type3)'
     if exists(select * from @P4) set @sql = @sql + ' and exists(select * from @P4 p where p.Id = t.Type4)'
     if exists(select * from @P5) set @sql = @sql + ' and exists(select * from @P5 p where p.Id = t.Type5)'
     if exists(select * from @P6) set @sql = @sql + ' and exists(select * from @P6 p where p.Id = t.Type6)'

     --print @sql 
     exec sp_executesql @sql, 
       N'@P1 TableType1 READONLY
        ,@P2 TableType2 READONLY
        ,@P3 TableType1 READONLY
        ,@P4 TableType2 READONLY
        ,@P5 TableType1 READONLY
        ,@P6 TableType2 READONLY',
        @p1 = @p1,
        @p2 = @p2,
        @p3 = @p3,
        @p4 = @p4,
        @p5 = @p5,
        @p6 = @p6

END;
```